# SQL Point of sale how does a return work

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im new to POS systems. I have to create a very simple one for a few stores. Here is my SQL Server DB Schema:

[image]

The question that I have is how to handle returns.

> In the real world how does a return works? Is a return a new sale but with a negative balance? If so then I would need to add to my sale table a "`transactiontype`" field (sale, return, etc.) and also a "`referencesaleuid`" field so the new sale (that will be a return) can reference the original sale ticket.

Comment: As an aside: I hope this is purely academic, and you're not *actually* deploying something like this to a real-world scenario. Storing credit card info is almost never a good idea, and unless you follow some very strict and expensive security procedures, having that info in your database leaves the business open to very large fines and perhaps even criminal charges.

Comment: Its going to be to real world but I'm following PCI Compliance. Just having those fields for better sample reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to handle returns is a business decision.

For one example, we have worked with retailers of larger ticket items that needed to match returned products back to the original line item.  So if a customer walked out of the store with two widgets and later returned one widget then we needed to be able to link the returned SKU back to the original transaction and SKU.

As another example, we have worked with retailers of smaller ticket items where returns were treated negative transactions.

I would suggest consulting closely with the business managers to find out what they would like to do in order to manage the business best.